# Why the command I put into rc.local didn't to work properly?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to execute a command  every time I boot up my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. this command is an .sh file located in `/root` directory and executed with an `start` argument. So my `rc.local` file look like this:

`/root/myscript.sh start
exit 0`

but it never worked. I added an `bash` in front of the script command, doesn't work neither.

If I started manually it will work well and print some message.

I'm going to try some other solutions,But right for now I'm very curious about the reason why this method doesn't work, and how can I work it out is this way ?

my script file is as follows (not written by me, I just downloaded it on github, and it contains comments which is not written in English) :

Comment: Please post the contents of `myscript.sh`. And `/root` is not a good place for scripts.

Comment: you did not manage to paste in your script actually

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use upstart.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it

Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/myscript.conf
```

Then write:

```
description "My Script for Ubuntu 14.04"
author "social_loser"
start on runlevel [2345]
exec Path_To_Script_Here
```

Save and close, then run:

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/myscript.conf
```

Everytime you'll turn on your PC the script will run.